# onItemSelected getting called late

Tags: android, spinner

I have code where 36 spinners are initialized with some default values.

Before initializing all of them, I am setting a value called listen to false.
After initializing all of them, I am setting it to true.

In the onItemSelected, I am executing code if listen is true.

I have thoroughly analyzed my code and discovered that onItemSelected is getting called AFTER, much much AFTER the spinners are set.
In fact, it is being called after the whole view itself is displayed.

There seems to be some time elapsed between me setting the spinner and onItemSelected being called. Isn't it called immediately?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code run through the initializing process of the spinner-elements, sets `listen = true`, you click, the rest of the view is getting initialized and then your `onItemSelected` gets called?

This would be because the click event will be stored in a queue until the `MainThread` has nothing else todo, but he is stuck with initializing the other view elements and first will return, if this has be done.

Why does your init-process for the whole view takes so long? If it is because of IO (Network/DB) you should read about the Loader-Pattern.

Comment: listen = false, spinners init, listen = true.
Then the whole view loads.
Then without any click, the onItemSelected is called.

Comment: And where do you call onItemSelected, when it is not automatically called via an UI-Event?

Comment: I do not call it myself. Is that even possible, btw?

Comment: Of course, it is a method, so you are able to call it. -- When initializing the spinner the onItemSelected-Event will be fired, this event will be queued in the Message-Queue of the MainThread. So this is quite a normal behaviour, what do you try to achieve or why is this a problem for you?

Comment: My problem is that it is getting fired at initialization.
To avoid this, I used the listen variable, by setting it to false, then setting it to true after the initialization.
But the method is getting called waaay after the listen is once again set to true.

Comment: Ah, okay! What about a simple counter? Start by zero, count it up every onItemSelected call, if counter > 1 do your stuff?

Comment: I thought of that too, and that works, but there's another problem:

The user has the option to click on "previous", upon which I change the selection of SOME of the spinners.
I could temporarily change the count value to some allowable value while the selection is getting changed, but the same problem would arise again: the function would get called AFTER the value is changed back.

Comment: But if you reset the counter of the affected spinners, why would there be any problem?